# node.js res: Response type is showing error

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to get some node.js and typescript working, but i have some basic issue.
I have created such routeController

```
  public allUsers = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "ERROR",
      message: "Not implemented",
    });
  };
```

My `res.status(500)` is showing me error:
`This expression is not callable.Type 'Number' has no call signatures.ts(2349)`

do i need to define some extra interface for this? or extend something?

Comment: which `Request` is this?

Comment: what do you mean? `this expression is not callable.
  Type 'Number' has no call signatures.ts(2349)`

Comment: No, I mean "what is `Request`" e.g. is it Node's request object? Express? Some other framework? Does it have TS definitions somewhere? etc. Typescript is complaining that the definition you gave it for that thing doesn't match the code you wrote, so: what is it, and where is TS looking for its type definitions.

Comment: aa okay :) `interface Response This Fetch API interface represents the response to a request.` i have: `@types/node, @types/express, ts-node, typescript` instlled

Comment: that's the response, not the request... but also, note that that still doesn't actually include the information on _which_ interface it is. Where is it loading that definition _from_? You already got an answer, but for future reference, this still matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are referencing the wrong `Request` type. Now that `fetch` is built in to Node, it's `Response` would be the default global type which defines `status: number`;

If you explicitly use the `express` (or whatever your HTTP framework is) types then you should be good.

```
import type {Request, Response} from 'express';

public allUsers = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "ERROR",
      message: "Not implemented",
    });
  };
```